# How To Save & Quit Vi in Terminal Emulator in Remix OS

Tags: android, terminal, save, android-5.0-lollipop, vi

I have a problem to save and quit vi editor in Remix OS.
I have changed some configuration in /system/etc/init.sh in Remix. Further, When I wanna to save and quit by clicking (Esc) and is followed by :wq and press Enter.

But it cannot work.

I tried to click (Esc), :wq! and it did not work too.

Please help me out. I would appreciate for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem if you are editing a root-owned file as yourself (like many of the files in /system). In this case you won't have permission to write the file.

Try starting vi as `sudo vi FILENAME` to edit as root or from vi entering the command `:w !sudo tee % >/dev/null` followed by `:q` which will sudo write and quit.